# Who gave the flute (murali) to lord Krishna?

Tags: krishna

Who gave the flute to lord Krishna? Where Lord Krishna got his flute from?

Answer (score 3):

Found this interesting story here about the [flute](http://www.bhagavatam-katha.com/vrindavan-story-how-bamboo-become-krishnas-flute/):

> One day Krsna saw one of His companions playing a flute, thus He also
>   desired to have a flute. Krishna’s flute has special life story. Flute
>   grow with all other bamboo sticks on bank of Yamuna. As thew grow all
>   bamboo sticks are very proud that they are growing so high in the sky.
>   But that one bamboo stick was very humble he was not going up, but
>   bending down. He was very humble and bend. He was performing great
>   austerities standing on one leg in water of Yamuna for long time.
>   Villagers are often coming on bank of Yamuna and they would cut all
>   this high growing bamboo sticks. Only one bamboo stick who was bend
>   down nobody touch. He was not useful to them. But that humble bamboo
>   stick was very patient. He was waiting for his day of perfection. One
>   day the Lord Sri Krishna himself came on bank of Yamuna. He was
>   looking for proper bamboo stick to make his own flute. Then from all
>   bamboo he chose the bamboo stick bending humbly down. From that bamboo
>   on the bank of the Yamuna River he constructed His divine flute.
>   Krsna’s belongings are not ordinary, hence His flute is supernatural.
>   After ascetics perform great austerities for many births they may
>   become a stick, ankle bell, or dress of Lord Krsna’s. Similarly the
>   bamboo stick used to make the Lord’s flute must also have performed
>   great austerities. When Krsna played His flute, the sound mesmerized
>   Lord Brahma, Lord Siva and all the movable and immovable entities in
>   the three worlds. The scriptures state Krsna’s flute is His main
>   weapon. By this weapon he conquer devotees hearth.

Another version [here](http://vishwanandalove.blogspot.ca/2011/09/beautiful-story-about-flute-of-krishna.html):

> A beautiful Story about the flute of Krishna: There is a beautiful
>   story about the flute of Krishna. You know Krishna always holds a
>   flute in his hand, but there is a great story behind it. Everyday
>   Krishna would go in the garden and say to all the plants, “I love
>   you”. The plants were very happy and responded back and said “Krishna,
>   we love You, too”. One day Krishna rushed quickly into the garden very
>   alarmed. He went to the bamboo plant and the bamboo plant asked,
>   “Krishna, what´s wrong with you?” Krishna said “I have something to
>   ask you, but it is very difficult”. The bamboo said “Tell me: if I
>   can, I will give it to you”. So Krishna said “I need your life. I need
>   to cut you”. The bamboo thought for a while and then said “You don´t
>   have any other choice. You don’t have any other way?” Krishna said,
>   “No, no other way”. And it said “OK, I surrender to you”. So Krishna
>   cut the bamboo, made holes in it, and each time, while he was doing
>   that, the bamboo was crying with pain, because he was paining the
>   bamboo so much. Krishna made a beautiful flute out of it. And this
>   flute was with Krishna all the time. 24 hours a day, it was with
>   Krishna. Even the Gopis were jealous of the flute. They said, “Look,
>   Krishna is our Lord, but yet we get to spend only some time with him.
>   He wakes up with you, He sleeps with you, all the time you are with
>   him”. So one day they asked the bamboo, “Tell us the secret of it.
>   What secret do you have, that the Lord treasures you so much?” And the
>   bamboo said “The secret is that I´m empty inside. And the Lord does
>   whatever he wants with me, whenever he wants with me and however he
>   wants with me”. So this is complete surrender: where God can do
>   whatever He wants with you, whenever He wants, as He wants. And for
>   that you don’t need to be scared, you know, you have just to give
>   yourself. And who is yourself in reality? It’s just Him!

Comment: can't find a scriptual source.

Comment: @Fiercelord me too, looking for one.